# revert tag:enw to tag:england-and-wales

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I propose we revert the recent re-tags. [england-and-wales](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) is much clearer and well-established on this site. If needed, we can add a tag synonym for [enw](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enw).

---

<sup>I raise this here instead of in a comment on the main site because the help page says, [When *shouldn't* I comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment): "Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead."</sup>

Comment: With all due respect you could have tried raising this with me in a comment before posting about it. In fact the purpose of the retags are to enable a proposal for a short alias to be created which would if I understand right effectively revert the retags anyway.

Comment: @Seekinganswers No, this is exactly what Meta is for. Having a discussion is useful for anyone else who gets the same idea. Vague acronym tags have a poor track record. If you think people might find a synonym more easily, propose it here and a moderator can take care of it.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, there is no [enw](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enw) tag in existence (anymore?) and it's impossible to make a synonym on a nonexistent tag.

ENW - like other acronyms - **should not be used as a tag**, as it might mean multiple things, [including 2 airstrips and a language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENW). A synonym should be considered the moment it crops up next time.